# unable to use content query webpart to retrieve the list content (custom template) from subsites

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, content-query-web-part, filter

I am unable to retrieve the list items via content query web part from all the sub sites of a custom list created with a template. This is a SharePoint online site collection and i have placed the web part at the site collection level.

Especially, few fields such as "Project" are not coming in the filter options.

Comment: Use same Content Type in all list in sub sites. And then get list item using content type from all sub sites in cqwp webpart

Comment: i have added the fields using item content type. still it is not showing.

Comment: Create custom content type and then try.

Comment: i have tried it and it works fine. but strangely only "Project" field which is a default site column is not coming in the filter options. also i could see that this field is not available to use in calculated fields.